# Delay before the Load event raises, on Windows 10 with a legacy Visual Basic 6 application

Tags: windows, performance, vb6, delay

We have a legacy VB6 application who use some custom activeX components developed for us. One of them has massive use in each form, due it's a textbox extension. This component has five VB6 contros (2 textbox, 2 frames, 1 label). Almost, it has a CommonControl Monthview component on a form.

The performance of the whole application has gone so fine until a year ago. Running under Windows 10, Windows Server 2019... each form, on depending on de number of instances of that control has, seems that freezes before de Load event is raised.

We've done lots of tests on differents machines, differents configurations, differents OS version, and the results of all those test are the same. On windows 7, a form with 160 instances of that object spends 0.4 seconds until the first line of the Load event is executed. The same version of the application, running under Windows 10, can spend between 5 and 12 seconds until the first line of code is executed. This range of time, between 5 and 12 seconds, is always over the same scenario, W10 with so similar hardware. For example, we have customers with 50 PC running the application, and each one has is own behavior. Some spend 5 seconds... others spend 12 seconds... and the major group of then take 6, 7, 8 seconds... Also, we've developed another custom activeX component, with the same controls on it but without any code. Only working as a container of other controls. The test with that control has more or less the same results. The major part of the time is wasted on the redraw and resize of the components inside that custom control.

We've readed that may be related with the graphic resources of each computer, the SO configuration and so on, but nothing clear. We've tried all the possible solutions provided by all that documentation we've readed, but nothing has worked for us.

Anyone can help us with this problem? Any idea, clue, test we can do... anything can help us to solve this situation.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In oder to give you some meaningful suggestions, you need to list what you tried so far. There's no point we repeat all suggestions you already tried. It's a waste of both your and our time.

Comment: DId you resarch `WM_SETREDRAW`?

Comment: Are any of these controls databound? If they're trying to fetch data from a database, especially a centrally located db, this could be a networking/routing/driver/provider/etc based issue, causing increased latency/delays in accessing the db.

Comment: @MarkL: I'm not sure how that would explain the performance difference seen in Win 7 <-> Win 10, the OP mentioned.